# calling a variable from one app to another in flask

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

i have the below apps in flask where one will receive an input from user.

the /vrf_extension app will render a html file where user enters a value. after that i want to get that variable and use it in /vrf_ext_config app. i have tried the below code with `session` but its not passing it to the /vrf_ext_config. do you know any other way i can achieve that.

```
--- app.py ---
@app.route('/vrf_ext_config', methods=["POST", "GET"])
def vrf_ext_config():
    if request.method == "POST":
        sa_name = session.get('sa_name')
        print(sa_name)
    return render_template("vrf_ext_config.html")


@app.route('/vrf_extension', methods=["POST", "GET"])
def vrf_extension():
    if request.method == "POST":
        session['sa_name'] = request.form["sa_name"]
        return render_template("vrf_ext_config.html")
    return render_template("vrf_extension.html")

---- vrf_extension.html ----
<title>VRF Extenstion</title>

{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<html>
<head>
</head>
            <body>
                <p><h3>Please Choose the Access Switch you would like to extend the VRF to: </h3>
                <form method="post" action="/vrf_extension">
                    <p> Please enter Access Switch name: <input name="sa_name"/></p>
                    <p><input type="submit" value="Go to Config Generator" /></p>
                </form>
            </body>
</html>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please change

```
<form method="post" action="/vrf_extension">
```

to

```
<form method="post" action="/vrf_ext_config">
```

in the HTML.

Comment: Then, let's do more conventional ```sa_name = request.form['sa_name']```